# AWS S3 File Upload, Optimal throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Use case**

---

- Upload from browser to S3 storage
- Optimize upload speed/throughput

Having the same bucket in all amazon regions, is it possible to have %BucketName%.s3.amazonaws.com route the upload to the closest bucket, and thus, optimizing upload throughput ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't, primarily because it's not possible to have the same bucket name in more than one region.

Only one bucket in all the entirety of S3 can have a given name.

> **“**The bucket namespace is global - just like domain names**”**
>
> — http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1109#02

The US Standard region [automatically routes requests to facilities in Northern Virginia or the Pacific Northwest using network maps](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LocationSelection.html) but this is the only region in S3 that supports any kind of documented geographic routing... and that routing comes at the (presumably-related) cost of eventual consistency on all operations, unlike all the other regions, which have read-after-write consistency for consistency for PUTS of new objects.